# How do i call a function everytime my entry is updated

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program, where i need to update something everytime, the user types in the entry. However I cant seem to find out how. Is it possible?

Comment: Try `<tkinter.Entry>.bind("<Key>", function)`

Comment: I realized i probably should have given som more context. I am trying to make a chemical reaction writer, that formats the user input in realtime using matplotlib and tkinter. When i use the bind function it does weird things, and it runs the given function before the letter is typed in the Entry.

Comment: Use `<tkinter.Entry>.bind("<Key>", function)` and then in that function just have `<tkinter.Entry>.after(0, the_real_function_after_key_press)`